# Who is the best counter to Anivia in lane?

Tags: league-of-legends

After level six she just seems to be able to farm and harass limitlessly and whenever I try to force a fight she walls me off and chunks me for half my health with her spear.

Who is the best counter to Anivia in lane?

Comment: Hi @Keenan, welcome to the site. Unfortunately, I'm voting to close your question as Not Constructive. We don't accept polling questions like this here because there are problems with inaccurate voting (people upvoting *champs* they like, rather than quality *answers*), list maintenance (keeping such lists up to date), and subjectivity (how do you determine "best"?) If you were to re-frame your question detailing more specific difficulties you are having when laning against Anivia, you would get more helpful answers and this could remain open.

Answer (score 2):

Being walled by Anivia is probably what makes her a dominate threat in games. One of the best counters to her is Kassadin, he can silence her, and blink around her wall and out of the range of her Q.

Other champions with dashes such as Ahri and LeBlanc also do well. TF is also another great pick as he can push just as well as her and then has his global ultimate to gank lanes.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to dodge her stun, but I would say that there is no counter to Anivia, everything depends on how YOU play, if you can't stay in lane with here, try to push and do objectives (dragon, stealing buffs) on the map with your jungler, or gank top/bot.

Answer (score 1):

i would say the best way to counter her mid lane is to take her teams blue buff.  she uses a lot of mana and if she gets blue buff she can just farm with her ult all day but if she doesnt get one her farming will be hurt and prevent her from farming as much.

Answer (score 0):

If i were to lane against Anivia i would pick Annie and flash r her to death every time that combo is up. Her q is relatively easy to dodge and you can play super aggressive pre 6 after dodging a q. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Swain is my go to champ for Anivia if you pick up some MR early to cut some dmg off her burst, then when i hit 6 i out sustain her and can start bullying.

But really watch for the Q as she sends it out and when it misses get in her face fast and punish her. Also DoT is handy for her passive if she goes down and you don't have enough time to finish the egg off (under tower, enemy jungle shows up) you can chuck the DoTs on then bail out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best counter against Anivia is Fizz.

With his Playful/Trickster (E) he can easily escape all of Anivias abilities (he can even jump over her Wall). This means that he can easily harrass her, because he can just jump away. By Level 6 Anivias should be on half her HP or even lower then you can go for the kill (or at least get her passive out)

Answer (score -2):

Just play [Fizz](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Fizz_the_Tidal_Trickster) and wait til level 6, then burst her with 1 ultimate combo.